# Run Hydra Through Series of Proxies?

Tags: proxy, hydra

Is there a way to run Hydra through a series of proxies so a website can't lock you out? Having a hard time finding a way to do this. Most websites will block you out if you take to many attempts at logging in and if I am trying to brute force a password, I am going to have to constantly have to look like I am coming from many different places.

Comment: Sure, but that's not a hydra thing, that's just a scripting thing. You need proxies first, and then you can simply use Python/Powershell or whatever you want to run a certain number of attempts through each proxy.

Comment: Figured it out. Just used the built in proxy chain function in Kali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains).